# ASP.net website is down after migrating the hosting servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, hosting, web-hosting

I have a website which was programmed by C# (ASP.net). The programmer uploaded the website to the host after a time the web hosting company migrated their servers then my website went down. The hosting company said it is not from their side and I know that the code does not change and the same code was working on the old servers. When trying to open the webpage it gave an empty page.
I hope that someone can give what the problem might be.

Thanks

Comment: Check the new web.config file against the old one and look for changes. Also see if the default page has been reset. If the old default page was MyHomePage.aspx you will need to add it, as it might be loading a blank default.aspx page.

Comment: I agree with Zerkey, however, if you do not come right, first of all change the error mode in web.config so at least you can have some detail about the problem. Then ask the hosting company about the framework allowed on their new server and make sure you meet the requirements. This is a starting point, then you may have to check connection string to your db and so on.